# How to copy a database (SQL Server 2008) to a different database (SQL Server 2000)

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, ssis

Okay so there are 2 computer servers. The one is running SQL Server 2008 and the other is SQL Server 2000. Let's call them DB1 and DB2. So Db1 (SQL Server 2008) is a production server. And everyday we need to backup DB1 server to DB2 server (SQL Server 2000). We have tried SSIS in VS 2008. It works great. However, any changes that will occur in the future pertaining to the database structure of Db1 (SQL Server 2008) will not be reflected in the mirrored database which is DB2 (SQL Server 2000) unless reconfigured manually. For example if in Db1 (SQL Server 2008), an admin added a table or add/delete columns in a certain table, the SSIS package will get an error thus we need to rebuild or reconfigure manually again in VS 2008. We don't want to do that from time to time, right?

Comment: What is the purpose of this 2005 server? Are you trying to use it as a data backup for disaster recovery... or do you use it for some other purpose and do normal backup procedures for disaster recovery?

Comment: You mean sql 2000 server? We use it as a backup. We just migrated from SQL 2000 to SQL 2008. We want to have SQL 2000 DB for backup or disaster recovery.

Answer (score 1):

This is a really bad idea.  You should use the standard backup features of SQL Server 2008.  You should also test your recovery process as well make sure that if you have a disaster that you will be able to recover your production server 100%.  It's really too much detail to get into here on all your options but look into the SQL Server Books to get a general overview of the process.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189621%28v=sql.100%29.aspx

As a starting base at the very minimum, set your databases to simple recovery model and do a full backup every night.  If you create a maintenance plan, it will kind of wizard your way though creating a simple backup plan to do a full backup on a schedule.  Then practice a restore to a different database name... just to be sure you know how it works.  As you learn more, you can enhance your disaster recovery plan by using full recovery model... etc.  I'm just worried that what you have in place now might not be enough to cover you if you have a catastrophic data loss situation.

Comment: Are you saying there's no way to do that in VISUAL STUDIO 2008? :(

Comment: You *can* copy the data to database tables into a SQL 2000 database for backups, but you shouldn't.  All of your procedures and views will eventually no longer have valid syntax as you start using 2008 features so you can't use it to back up those.  It's actually way more work to try to do what you are wanting rather than just using the standard and recommended backup process and you're going to miss something in the process and risk data loss.  Why are you trying to avoid it?

Comment: Hi Brian, Forgot to tell you that some one our systems here are still running sql 2000. Since it's complicated we're thinking to abandon the idea of mirroring sql 2008 to 2000.